# put a string to an item depending on its key in ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects.

```
$scope.array [
 {beast: 'rat', color: 'red', price: 5000, 'size', '100 kg'},
 {beast: 'cat', color: 'white', price: 4000, 'size', '500 kg'},
 {beast: 'bird', color: 'pink', price: 3000, 'size', '200 kg'}
]
```

in my html i have:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='search'>
<p ng-repeat = "a in array | filter: search"></p>
```

I want  to begin to show items when writing a text field.
I want to filter only by "animal" or "color" through a text field.

but I want if I write part of the name of the animal, it appears, for example, i write "ra", appears on the item:

```
animal -> rat
```

if I write 're', should appear in the list:

```
color -> red
```

but if I write 'r', for this example, 2 item that should appear starting with 'r'

```
animal -> rat
color -> red
```

which is not the best way to do this, I'm new angular.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ I have tried many things, even I created a filter. but I do not get my result. This is an example for the answer I need.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ   It is somewhat different to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a plunkr that may help understand things a bit:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jSiFb1Y0yQw5y7d06LXf

It can be refactored heavily and optimized, but I left it as that to hopefully shed some light into how things work.

Basically, its a simple filter.  Every filter receives first the items, and then any other parameter you pass to it.  Inside, you can work any solution you like.

In my solution, I add simple if conditionals inside.  You can, of course, use regExps or other solutions to parse objects.

The main solution is to first define the array correctly (the above code is missing equals and the object definition is missing some semicolons):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
   {beast: 'rat', color: 'red', price: 5000, size: '100 kg'},
   {beast: 'cat', color: 'white', price: 4000, size: '500 kg'},
   {beast: 'bird', color: 'pink', price: 3000, size: '200 kg'}
  ];
});
```

And then there is the filter:

```
app.filter('searchData', function() {
  return function(items, searchText) {
    var results = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.beast.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
        results.push('beast -> ' + item.beast);
      }

      if(item.color.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
        results.push('color -> ' + item.color);
      }
    });

    return results;
  };
});
```

Also, on the ng-repeat of the P element, you need to actually output something inside so that it shows, otherwise, it is repeating empty Ps:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='search'>
<p ng-repeat = "item in data | searchData : search ">{{item}}</p>
```

Hope this helps,

Best regards,

Rafa.

**UPDATE**
If you don't want the results to show upon deleting all the input, a simple if before the each will do:

```
app.filter('searchData', function() {
  return function(items, searchText) {
    var results = [];

    if(searchText) {
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.beast.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
          results.push('beast -> ' + item.beast);
        }

        if(item.color.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
          results.push('color -> ' + item.color);
        }
      });
    }

    return results;
  };
});
```

I have updated the plunker with this solution.

Comment: thank you! you are very smart. I have a doubt. The first time you look for something the list is generated. This is good. but when I delete the word in the text field, all objects are listed. How do I fix this ?. I want the list is generated when you start typing.

Comment: muchas gracias! eres muy inteligente. tengo una duda. La primera vez que busco algo se genera la lista. esto esta bien. pero cuando borro la palabra del campo de texto, se listan todos los objetos. Cómo soluciono esto?. quiero que se genere la lista cuando empiece a escribir.

Comment: I´m updating the answer with that in mind.  If this answer works for you, I'd appreciate it you mark it as a correct answer ;)

Comment: can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531738/returning-and-calling-an-object-in-a-list-angular-js/34534029#34534029 thank you!

Comment: I have answered there, seems like a continuing of this same question though. :)