# returning and calling an object in a list (ANGULAR.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in this example I'm returning a string depending on whether a text field is a value for "beast" and/or "color". but this is only returning a string. I would return in two conditions that have an object:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fSut1gqIKFAEej8UdbmE?p=preview

in the first conditional I need create an object and return:

```
{name: item.beast, type: "animal"}
```

in the second conditional, I need create an object and :

```
{name: item.color, type: "color of animal"}
```

and then in the HTML file, would that I could put the list:

```
{{ item.name }} and {{item.type}}
```

so if I type "r" should appear in the list:

```
"rat and animal"
"red and color of animal "
```

Comment: I am wondering why it got many upvotes *-*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to get. Have a look at this plunk. Is this what you wanted ?

It works if you push the whole item to the results list like:

```
results.push(item);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xW9hqC1z1rKddRWaP2g6?p=preview

Comment: @Alox 
thanks for responding, but notes that want to create an object, and that object I am creating in the 2 conditional. the new object has two new properties "name" and "type".

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExmFtafBqrsNNXGgH4J5?p=preview)

```
 app.service('myFactoryService', function(){
  this.createObj = function(name,type){
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = name;
    obj.type = type;
    return obj;
  }
});

results.push(myFactoryService.createObj(item.beast,"animal"));
```

I don't know somehow why two-way binding doesn't permit to show two variables differently, only object, but there is defined service to create an object, then it is created in filter according to both options.

Comment: I agree that it is weird that the **{{item.name}} and {{item.type}}** approach does not work... it would be much 'cleaner'.  But, for the time being this works: `{{item.name + ' and ' + item.type}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can return objects inside the filter, exactly as you have written them on your question (also, I have cleaned up a bit the ifs... don't use document.getElementById inside the filter, you have the searchText in there already as second parameter of the filter!):

```
app.filter('searchData', function() {
  return function(items, searchText) {
    var results = [];

    if(searchText) {

      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.beast.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
          results.push({ name: item.beast, type: 'animal' });
        }

        if(item.color.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
          results.push({ name: item.color, type: 'color of animal' });
        }
      });
    }

    return results;
  };
});
```

And then, you can use this on the P object of the html:

```
<p ng-repeat = "item in data | searchData : search">{{item.name + ' and ' + item.type}}</p>
```

I have forked the plunkr here with the changed code:

**http://plnkr.co/edit/EDd578?p=preview**

Hope it helps,

Best regards,

Rafa.

ps. Also, remember always to use the equality operators !== or === in Javascript, and not the != and == forms.

Comment: friend..can you look the console?? there is a error.. "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"