# Two way binding doen't work when using variable twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have standard array with objects. 
When i use once variable in ng-repeat block, then it is showing fine by two way binding. If i use the variable twice in same block, it fails. 
Why?

```
  <ul>
       <li ng-repeat = "item in data | searchData : search ">{{item.type}}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
       <li ng-repeat = "item in data | searchData : search ">{{item.type}} and {{item.type}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Results when i type "r":

```
animal
color
{{item.type}} and {{item.type}}
{{item.type}} and {{item.type}}
```

As i know Angular, it should change item.type to "animal" and "color". So why it is so?
Look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExmFtafBqrsNNXGgH4J5?p=preview) i am creating array of objects conditionally in filter and creating object in service, but as i know i am returning objects. It's 1.4 version, is it case?

> plnkr

Comment: Try adding the second binding in span or div.

Comment: Just FYI, I started a [discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313697/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-to-help-you-complete-an-answer-you-are-writing) about this question which looks related to [another answer you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531738/returning-and-calling-an-object-in-a-list-angular-js/34534029#34534029).

Comment: It's because you are getting `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`.